# JavaScript to display hidden layers depending on selection from JQuery Flexbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show, layer

What I have is a set of 3 Jquery flexbox combo boxes (dropdowns).  The first one is visible, the other 2 are hidden.

What I want is to have the selection from the first box determine which layer gets revealed for box 2, and in turn have the selection from box 2 reveal the appropriate layer for box 3. I then want the selection from box 3 to reveal a fourth layer - the 'results'.

I need help figuring out a JavaScript function that will work with JQuery Flexbox, to reveal the appropriate divs.

In the head tag:

```
function showlayer(layer){
    var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer).style.display;
    if(myLayer == "none"){
        document.getElementById(layer).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(layer).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This may or may not be a good way to start with the layer reveal script.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //a flexbox with 3 different types of providers
    //each selection would reveal a different city list (box2)
    $('#ffb1').flexbox(providers, {
        watermark: 'Please choose a provider type',
        width: 260,                   
        autoCompleteFirstMatch: false 
        onSelect: function change(){
            $("div[id^='box_']").show()  //this is the problem here, I think - how do I finish this off?
        });

    $('#ffb2').flexbox(cities, {
        watermark: 'Choose your city',
        width: 260,
    });

    $('#ffb3').flexbox(districts, {
        watermark: 'Choose your location',
        width: 260,
    });
});
```

and markup:

```
<div id="box_1">
    <table class=demo>
        <tbody>
            <tr class=example>
                <td><span>Provider type</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=col><b>Please choose the type of provider you are seeking:</B>
                <div style="height: 18px"></div>
                <div id=ffb1></div>
                <div style="clear: both" id=ffb7-result></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="box_2a" style="display:none;">
    <table class=demo>
        <tbody>
            <tr class=example>
                <td><span>City list 1</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=col><b>Please select the city closest to you:</B>
                <div style="height: 18px"></div>
                <div id=ffb2></div>
                <div style="clear: both" id=ffb7-result></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="box_2b" style="display:none;">
    <table class=demo>
        <tbody>
            <tr class=example>
                <td><span>City list 2</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=col><b>Please select the city closest to you:</B>
                <div style="height: 18px"></div>
                <div id=ffb2></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="box_2c" style="display:none;">
    <table class=demo>
        <tbody>
            <tr class=example>
                <td><span>City list 3</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=col><b>Please select the city closest to you:</B>
                <div style="height: 18px"></div>
                <div id=ffb2></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="box_3" style="display:none;">
    <table class=demo>
        <tbody>
            <tr class=example>
                <td><span>City Districts</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=col><b>Please choose a location:</B>
                <div style="height: 18px"></div>
                <div id=ffb2></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="box_4" style="display:none;">
    <table class=demo>
        <!-- results table would go here -->
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you have jQuery, you could be using just `$('#layerid').show()` and `$('#layerid').hide()`.

Comment: Changing z-index's on the selected elements may also be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm game for either approach but what I don't know is how to do this within Flexbox. I'm assuming I need to have a show function for each option in my list? 
something like:

$('#layerid').show(option1);
$('#layerid').show(option2);
$('#layerid').show(option3);
?

I have looked for documentation or examples but haven't found any yet.